# Show that $A^TA=I_n\rightarrow (A\vec{x})\cdot (A\vec{y})=\vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}$ $\forall \vec{x},\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I start by assuming that $A^TA=I_n$ holds, but I don't know how to obtain the right-hand side from this. Some ideas I've had were multiplying both sides by $\vec{x}$, but I still don't see how this can help us (since we ultimately need a dot product between between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are column vectors, then $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}$ is the same as the matrix product $\vec{x}^T\vec{y}$.  So $(A\vec{x})\cdot(A\vec{y})=(A\vec{x})^TA\vec{y}=\vec{x}^TA^TA\vec{y}$