# Show that $(A\vec{x})\cdot (A\vec{y})=\vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}\implies \|A\vec{x}\|=\|\vec{x}\|$

Tags: linear-algebra

Since we know the first expression is equivalent to $A^TA=I_n$, I was thinking we can multiple by $\vec{x}$ on both sides to get $A^TA\vec{x}=\vec{x}$ and once we take the magnitude on both sides we have $\|A^TA\vec{x}\|=\|\vec{x}\|$, but how can we remove the $A^T$?

Comment: If you look at $\lVert A\vec{x}\rVert^2$, do you see something?

Comment: @DanielFischer no, I'm sorry.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1006746/721644).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $(A\vec{x})\cdot (A\vec{y})=\vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}$ if $\|A\vec{x}\|=\|\vec{x}\| \ \forall\vec{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215880/prove-that-a-vecx-cdot-a-vecy-vecx-cdot-vecy-if-a-vecx)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\|v\|^2=v\cdot v=v^Tv$. Use this to check $\|Ax\|^2=\|x\|^2$.

Comment: How is this applicable to the expression $||A^TA\vec{x}||=||\vec{x}||$?

Comment: $\|Ax\|^2=(Ax)\cdot (Ax)=(Ax)^T(Ax)$. In essence, you only need to set $y=x$ in the assumption.

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that $||Ax||^2=||x||$ then?

Comment: @JohnReemer Is $||Ax||$ positive, or negative?

Comment: @awllower positive, of course.

Comment: @JohnReemer So you know that squares of two positive numbers are equal, and then...?

Comment: So $||Ax||^2=||x||^2$?

Answer (score 0):

If $A^{T}A=I_{n}$, then note that $||Ax||=\sqrt{(Ax)^{T}(Ax)}=\sqrt{x^{T}A^{T}Ax}=\sqrt{x^{T}I_{n}x}=\sqrt{x^{T}x}=||x||$.