# Prove that $(A\vec{x})\cdot (A\vec{y})=\vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}$ if $\|A\vec{x}\|=\|\vec{x}\| \ \forall\vec{x}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

How should I prove that$$(A\vec{x})\cdot (A\vec{y})=\vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}$$

if $$\|A\vec{x}\|=\|\vec{x}\|,\ \forall \vec{x}$$

could you help me to solve this step-by-step? Thank you!

Comment: Expand $\| Ax - Ay\|^2=\|x-y\|^2$

Comment: Its true if $A$ is  an orthogonal matrix meaning $A^T = A^{-1}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $(A\vec{x})\cdot (A\vec{y})=\vec{x}\cdot \vec{y}\implies \|A\vec{x}\|=\|\vec{x}\|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006774/show-that-a-vecx-cdot-a-vecy-vecx-cdot-vecy-implies-a-vecx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t see how this is true. If we have

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$x = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}, y = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

then $||A \overrightarrow x|| = 1 = ||\overrightarrow x||$ but $(A \overrightarrow x) \cdot (A \overrightarrow y) = 1 \neq 0 = \overrightarrow x \cdot \overrightarrow y$.

Perhaps you meant $||A \overrightarrow x|| = ||\overrightarrow x||$ for *all* $\overrightarrow x$. In this case, your statement is indeed true, so perhaps you should clarify exactly what each of your terms mean. It’s a little bit ambiguous currently.

Comment: Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there an exception for A? I like rain too btw:)

Comment: Its not true in this interpretation, but if you take the second line to mean $A$ is distance preserving then its true

Comment: @CalvinKhor but is my $A$ here not distance preserving?

Comment: No, with your $x,y$, $A(x-y)=0$ right?

Comment: Oh, so you mean $||A \overrightarrow x|| = || \overrightarrow x|| \forall \overrightarrow x \implies$ it is true?

Comment: Yeah. Im not OP, but that makes it true

Comment: Got it. I’m guessing that’s what OP meant too then.

Comment: Its true if $A$ is unimodular.